# Mark file icons with emblems like in Ubuntu in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu

A while ago I was playing with an older version of Ubuntu, which allowed me to mark the files with an emblem that appears on top of the file's icon.
I'm wondering if I can do the same thing in Windows. I am watching several series, but sometimes I get bored of one and I want to watch something else. So I want to mark my progress. If there is no way to do this in the filesystem itself, can I do it in a media player? (I'm Using MPC-HS).

Comment: Windows can do this but (as usual) they've messed it up to the point that it is unusable. They have a limit of 15 overlays. The problem is that this means you'll quickly run out. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools.aspx

Comment: Thanks Microsoft. The Best alternative I could Find Was [IWatchSeriez](https://github.com/csomakk/IWatchSeriez) but its buggy.

Comment: hey there. I wrote IWatchSeriez. What bugs did you found?